# Visual Studio 2015 - "Recently Finished" Code Reviews showing no results

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015, tfs-code-review

Our team is using TFS 2015 and Visual Studio 2015 update 2. In My Work under Code Reviews, there is nothing showing up when any team member selects the "Recently Finished" query. I was able to find this Microsoft discussion on the topic:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1777064/recently-finished-code-reviews-is-empty-in-vs2013-and-vs2015-after-update-to-tfs-2015

But it doesn't really help us. We've already upgraded to 2015 update 2, which is supposed to fix the issue. None of us have any special characters in our names, and all of our names are unique - two things which are cited as causing problems.

As suggested by a user on that thread, when I edit the query to use my actual name instead of "@Me" it works, but this doesn't explain why @Me isn't working and I can't find anywhere to change the default behavior, so it has to be edited each time I want to pull up completed workflows.  It is also considerably less user friendly to browse code reviews in the query editor as opposed to Team Explorer.

Anyone have any thoughts on what our issue might be?

Comment: Only the Recently Finished can't be seen or all of the status such as recently closed also can't be seen?

Comment: From your question it seems that is is only Visual Studio that you have upgraded to Update 2. What about TFS, is the the RTM version?

Answer (score 1):

I observed the same behavior is Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 with Visual Studio Team Services.

If you're using an on-prem installation of TFS you can modify the process template to work around this issue as described [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/07/28/code-review-default-queries-not-fetching-data-after-upgrading-to-tfs-2015/).

> 1. Perform the witadmin changefield command to set the SyncNameChanges value true for the collection
>
>    ```
>    witadmin.exe changefield /collection:collectionurl /n:"Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReviewedBy" /syncnamechanges:true
>    ```
> 2. Export the Code Response work item template from the team project
>
>    ```
>    witadmin.exe exportwitd /collection:collectionurl /p:projectname /f:workitem file path /n:"Code Review Response"
>    ```
> 3. Replace the field definition in the work item from VSTS.Common.ReviewedBy and Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy with the line below
>
>    ```
>    <FIELD name="Reviewed By" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ReviewedBy" type="String" syncnamechanges="true">
>        <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
>        <VALIDUSER />
>    </FIELD>
>    <FIELD name="Closed By" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedBy" type="String" syncnamechanges="true" reportable="dimension" >
>        <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
>        <VALIDUSER />
>    </FIELD>
>    ```
> 4. Import the Code Review Response work item back to the team project
>
>    ```
>    witadmin.exe importwitd /collection:collectionurl /p:projectname /f:workitem file path
>    ```

If you're using Visual Studio Team Services, modifying the process template isn't an option so I created a bug here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/46873/microsoftvstscommonreviewedby.html

Comment: This will turn from a good answer to a great one if you quote the relevant instructions into your answer. From [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer): "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."